# adding image to listView

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I have this problem. I want to add image to listView. Exactly I want use openFileDialog for choose image on disc,  load file to aplication and show them in listView.

Now I do it like this:

```
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "png (*.png)|*.png";
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        if ( openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {    
            string[] files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

            foreach ( var pngFile in files ) {
                try {
                    Bitmap image = new Bitmap( pngFile );
                    imageList1.Images.Add( image );
                } catch {
                }
            }
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
            listView1.Refresh();
        }
```

But it doesn't work. What do I make wrong?

## edit

I get blank listView. Nothing error.

Comment: You are getting some error? Or just blank listView?

Comment: I edit my post, there is answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's fine.  But you only added an image to the image list.  You haven't modified an item in the list view that actually *uses* that added image.  Add this line of code and tweak as necessary:

```
  listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("Added an image", imageList1.Images.Count - 1));
```

Also ensure that listView1.LargeImages = imageList1.  You set that in the designer.